# Glossary: list of acronyms with sub-categories

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I am trying to print a list of acronyms using the [`glossaries`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) package.

Sometimes, I have nested acronyms, where an acronym includes another.
Here is a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[indexonlyfirst,numberline,nopostdot,toc,hyperfirst=false]{glossaries}

\newacronym{QKD}{QKD}{Quantum Key Distribution}
    \newacronym[parent=QKD]{CV-QKD}{CV-QKD}{Continuous Variable \glstext{QKD}}
    \newacronym[parent=QKD]{DV-QKD}{DV-QKD}{Discrete Variable \glstext{QKD}}
    \newacronym[parent=QKD]{MDI-QKD}{MDI-QKD}{Measurement Device Independent \glstext{QKD}}
\newacronym{OA}{OA}{Other Acronym}
\newacronym{AE}{AE}{Acronym Example}


\makeglossaries{}

\begin{document}
    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={Abbreviations}]
    \section{Section 1}
        \gls{QKD} is the main acronym. We can also have subcategories of \gls{QKD} such as \gls{CV-QKD}, \gls{DV-QKD}, or \gls{MDI-QKD}.

        Other acronyms exist such as \gls{OA} or \gls{AE}.
\end{document}
```

However, this produces the following:

[image]

I would like to have a list formatted like this:

```
- Acronym + Definition
- Acronym + Definition
--Subacronym + Definition
--Subacronym + Definition
-Acronym + Definition
```

An alternative might be using the `alttree` style:

```latex
\usepackage[indexonlyfirst,numberline,nopostdot,toc,hyperfirst=false,style=alttree]{glossaries}
```

Which seems to do what I want, but it results in an overlap between the acronym and its definition:

[image]

Is it possible to solve this (either by fixing this or by using another style), as well as increasing the indentation of the sub-acronyms?

---

EDIT:

I did manage to sort this out, as per [this guide](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-styles):

> If you forget to set the widest entry, the description will overlap the name.

This solves the issue, however the indentation of the sub-acronyms is now too big, as it indents it at the description level.

[image]

My question now becomes, how do I **reduce** the indentation?

Answer (score 1):

Could you share, how you solved the problem?

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: This should really be a comment.