# Glossary acronym using a different way to display an entry

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I am currently writing my thesis, and I created a list of acronyms at the end of my manuscript with the glossary package :

```
\usepackage[acronym,toc,shortcuts]{glossaries}
...
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=List of Acronyms, toctitle=List of Acronyms]
```

At some point, I want to refer to the *Bidirectional and Unidirectional Long Short Term Memory* algorithms:

```
\newacronym{LSTM}{LSTM}{Long Short Term Memory}
\newacronym{B-LSTM}{B-LSTM}{Bidirectional LSTM} 
\newacronym{U-LSTM}{U-LSTM}{Unidirectional LSTM}
```

But to make it in a shorter way, I want to display it like that: *U- and B-LSTM*: `(U- and \acrshort{B-LSTM})`

Is there a way to use the `U-LSTM` acronym by printing just `U-` instead and still have it fully in the acronym list?

Comment: Are you planning on referring to the page or number or enabling hyperlinks? One alternative is make a dummy entry for B and U LSTM and add it but not print it to the main text, and make entries for the individual ones but not add to the glossary table.

Comment: Yeah, I am using the hyperlink and the page number of the references. But I did not really understand what you mean by dummy entry. Can I add entries to the Glossary that are not printed? (I know it's possible to print all the entries defined, even if they are not used. But is it possible for just one entry?)

Comment: I think you could glsadd the B and U LSTM. Check out the documentation, it's helpful. Ultimately though, I don't see what's wrong with including both. Maybe you want a sub-glossary for LSTM, and that's something to be looked up also...

Answer (score 0):

The mear-minimal example below works for me:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[pdftex, colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyperfirst = false, acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries{}

\newacronym{LSTM}{LSTM}{Long Short Term Memory}
\newacronym{B-LSTM}{B-LSTM}{Bidirectional LSTM} 
\newacronym{U-LSTM}{U-LSTM}{Unidirectional LSTM}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

Here, I'm referring to \glslink{U-LSTM}{U-} and \acrshort{B-LSTM}. 

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=List of Acronyms]

\end{document}
```

As noted by @likethevegetable, using sub-entries (like in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520829/glossary-list-of-acronyms-with-sub-categories); also section 4.5 of the userguide) may be more appropriate. Something like:

```
...
\usepackage[hyperfirst = false, acronym, style=tree]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries{}

\newacronym{LSTM}{LSTM}{Long Short Term Memory}
  \newacronym[parent=LSTM]{B-LSTM}{B-LSTM}{Bidirectional \glstext{LSTM}} 
  \newacronym[parent=LSTM]{U-LSTM}{U-LSTM}{Unidirectional \glstext{LSTM}}
...
 This is about \gls{LSTM}. Here, I'm referring to \glslink{U-LSTM}{U-} and \acrshort{B-LSTM}.
...
```